Nuclear spaces: the Schwartz class
Good morning, I'm studying quantum mechanics as a mathematician.
I read that the Schwartz class
$$\begin{equation*}
     \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) := \{ \varphi \in \mathcal{C}^\infty (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})  :  \forall p,q \in \mathbb{N} \quad \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |x^p \, \partial^q \varphi(x)| < +\infty \}
 \end{equation*}$$
is a nuclear space. I can't find a good textbook where to read a proof of this statement.
Does anyone know one that has, with a student friendly proof?
Thanks in advance.

This is treated in Chapter 3 of Quantum Mechanics in
Rigged Hilbert Space Language by Rafeal de la Madrid

Greatly appreciated, thanks
